# API for photo of caller in Bluetooth HFP for Android M or Android N

Tags: android-bluetooth, android-7.0-nougat, hfp

Is there any APIs available for showing the photo/Image of the caller(saved contacts) on the **Bluetooth HFP call** on HeadUnit in **Android M** or **Android N**.Please let me know.

N.B: Its available for Phone applications. Here I am asking about HFP call.

Answer (score 1):

HFP itself does not included the photo/Image of the contract you mentioned but only indicate the phone number etc.
In order to do that, you need another profile i.e. PBAP to pull the contract from phone side(in which the caller's photo/image can included in the v-card) to headunit, then the headunit itself first got the phone number from HFP, then search it from local contract database which got from phone.If the contract exists, just display it.

Comment: I am getting the Contact details with name and photo of caller in call log of my Android Bluetooth Phone Applications for remote BT devices in Android N.

I want a confirmation. Is it mean that the PBAP session is connected?

Comment: To confirm whether you connected, you might as well to check the btsnoop log, to see whether it is really ever connected.